# How can measure application performance on browser while Functional Automation Suite is running?

Tags: performance, selenium, performance-testing, browser-testing

Is there any tool or plugin which we can incorporate with existing Functional Automation Test suite.

Earlier till 2011-12 we were using Dynatrace Ajax edition. It was a plugin for Chrome and IE. We had configured this plugin into Selenium Test case. When these Selenium test were executing it was running all functional scenarios of application and parallel that Dynatrace tool was capturing performance stats for each actions performing on the application. At last we were getting a consolidate Performance report along with the Selenium test results.

But now I am not able to get any such kind of tool,plugin etc. which will help us to capture Performance stats of application with Selenium suit run.

Please help me in finding suitable way for it.

Comment: Is this what you want? - https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/leverage-your-load-testing-using-jmeter-and-selenium-webdriver/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are using ChromeDriver you can enable performance logging. I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
logPrefs.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.ALL);
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:9515"), cap);
```

The above code is what you will use the enable the logging for your session.

You don't need any kind of plugin/extensions for this. It uses Chrome's own performance logging feature.

Let me know if you are looking for this specifically.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is more of an opinion than a true answer to your question, but IMHO it's not so useful to measure the performance as part of your normal functional test cycle.

Measuring performance as part of a regular functional test cycle can provide you with a lot of performance data, but it won't tell you much. If you want to measure performance effectively, you should start with the question: what operation do I care to measure? And "Everything" is not the right answer... Then you have to define what performance do expect and under which circumstances. Then you should build a test and a corresponding environment to match these requirements. In addition, performance is usually not a fixed value, as it can be affected by many factors that we can't control (like external processes that may be running in the background). Therefore you should usually define the expected performance in statistical terms, like: 90% of the times, the measured operation should take no more than 3 seconds. This means that you should run the test at least 10 times (actually much more in order to be safe) in order to determine if the performance is good enough or not.